# How do I conditionally render an object to display one section of code if the object is not empty and one section of code if the object has key: value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, rendering

I am trying to render a section of code if the object UPCOMING has data, and a different section of code if the object doesn't have data. The issue I am running into is when the object is empty, the key/value pairs used later in the code are throwing an error.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import BasicCard from 'pages/EventsPage/EventsCard/index'
import EventsHeroImage from 'assets/images/events-hero-image.jpg'
import EventsHeroImageMobile from 'assets/images/events-mobile-hero-image.jpeg'
import CountdownTimer from 'pages/EventsPage/CountdownTimer/CountdownTimer'
import PlaceholderUpcomingShowImageDesktop from 'assets/images/placeholder-upcomng-show-image.png'
import PlaceholderUpcomingShowImageMobile from 'assets/images/placeholder-upcomng-show-image.png'
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import useStyles from './styles'

const EVENTS = [
  {
    month: 'AUG',
    day: '09',
    title: 'SUMMER 2019 SHOWCASE',
    time: '7:30PM-9:00PM',
    location: 'The Irenic, San Diego, CA',
  },
  {
    month: 'APR',
    day: '17',
    title: 'SPRING 2019 SHOWCASE',
    time: '7:30PM-9:00PM',
    location: 'The Irenic, San Diego, CA',
  },
  {
    month: 'AUG',
    day: '09',
    title: 'FALL 2019 SHOWCASE',
    time: '7:30PM-9:00PM',
    location: 'The Irenic, San Diego, CA',
  },
  {
    month: 'APR',
    day: '17',
    title: 'WINTER 2019 SHOWCASE',
    time: '7:30PM-9:00PM',
    location: 'The Irenic, San Diego, CA',
  },
]
const UPCOMINGEVENT = {
  title: 'WINTER 2020 SHOWCASE',
  date: 'JAN 24TH',
  location: 'THE IRENIC, SAN DIEGO',
  about:
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Consectetur cursus nunc faucibus justo enim, eget dignissimlacus turpis. Tincidunt sed mauris in volutpat. Sapien fringilla libero, facilisis elementum nisi lobortis amet porttitor. Velit risus diam sit feugiat velit enim et, euismodquis.',
}

const EventsPage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [events, setEvents] = useState(EVENTS)
  const { title, date, location, about } = UPCOMINGEVENT
  const startDate = '04/23/2021'
  const endDate = '05/04/2021'
  return (
    <div>
      {/*-------------Mobile View--------------------- */}
      <Grid
        container
        direction='column'
        justify='center'
        alignItems='center'
        spacing={0}
        className={classes.allContainerMobile}
      >
        <div className={classes.headingContainerMobile}>
          <div>
            <p className={classes.allEventsTitleMobile}>ALL EVENTS</p>
          </div>
          {!UPCOMINGEVENT ? (
            <div>
              <div className={classes.parentDivImageMobile}>
                <div className={classes.ImageDivMobile}>
                  <img
                    src={EventsHeroImageMobile}
                    className={classes.placeHolderImageMobile}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <Grid item sm={12} className={classes.gridMobile}>
                <div className={classes.countdownContainerMobile}>
                  <div className={classes.countdownParentMobile}>
                    <CountdownTimer
                      countdown={startDate}
                      unixEndDate={endDate}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </div>
          )}
          {!UPCOMINGEVENT ? (
            <div>
              <div>
                <p className={classes.upcomingShowMobile}>UPCOMING SHOW</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p className={classes.noUpcomingShowsMobile}>
                  NO UPCOMING SHOWS...FOR NOW.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <div className={classes.flyerImageMobile}>
                <div className={classes.upcomingShowParentMobile}>
                  <img
                    src={PlaceholderUpcomingShowImageMobile}
                    className={classes.imageStyleMobile}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        {UPCOMINGEVENT ? (
          <div>
            <div className={classes.upcomingShowsMobile}>
              <div className={classes.titleContainerMobile}>
                <p className={classes.upcomingShowTitleMobile}>
                  {/* {UPCOMINGEVENT.title} */}
                  {title}
                </p>
                {/* <p className={classes.upcomingShowTitleMobile}>
                  WINTER 2020 SHOWCASE
                </p> */}
              </div>
              <div className={classes.dateLocationContainerMobile}>
                <p className={classes.upcomingShowDateLocationMobile}>
                  {/* {UPCOMINGEVENT.date} | {UPCOMINGEVENT.location} */}
                  {date} | {location}
                </p>
                {/* <p className={classes.upcomingShowDateLocationMobile}>
                  JAN 24TH | THE IRENIC, SAN DIEGO
                </p> */}
              </div>
              <div className={classes.aboutContainerMobile}>
                <p className={classes.aboutUpcomingShowMobile}>
                  {/* {UPCOMINGEVENT.about} */}
                  {about}
                </p>
                {/* <p className={classes.aboutUpcomingShowMobile}>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                  Consectetur cursus nunc faucibus justo enim, eget
                  dignissimlacus turpis. Tincidunt sed mauris in volutpat.
                  Sapien fringilla libero, facilisis elementum nisi lobortis
                  amet porttitor. Velit risus diam sit feugiat velit enim et,
                  euismodquis.
                </p> */}
              </div>
              <div className={classes.upcomingShowButtonContainerMobile}>
                <button className={classes.upcomingShowButtonMobile}>
                  BUY TICKETS
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : null}
        {!UPCOMINGEVENT ? (
          <div>
            <h2 className={classes.pastShowsMobile}>PAST SHOWS</h2>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h2 className={classes.pastShowsUpcomingMobile}>PAST SHOWS</h2>
          </div>
        )}

        <div className={classes.eventsCardMobile}>
          {events.map(({ month, day, title, time, location }, i) => (
            <BasicCard
              key={`${title}-${i}`}
              month={month}
              day={day}
              title={title}
              time={time}
              location={location}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Grid>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the error message with us?

Comment: When the object is empty there are no key: value pairs, and I call on the values later in the code to display them when there is a key: value pair. I guess the issue is I do not know how to make the UPCOMINGEVENT object display the proper code when there is no data. Is it something with the state? Should I make the upcoming event object start off empty and then somehow change state to contain keys/values?

Comment: @Ayaz     This is the error I am getting: Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: and this error: Object is possibly 'null'

Answer (score 0):

When the object is empty,  does it get the value undefined or null?  Or does it get the value length 0? I'm thinking you maybe should use "Object.keys(obj).length === 0" as a conditional.

Comment: The UPCOMINGEVENT object has keys: title, date, location, and about. I used those keys later on in the code (ex: <p>{UPCOMINGEVENT.date} | {UPCOMINGEVENT.location}</p>. The issue I am having is when I make the object null, it throws an error saying title, date, location and about are not found. My question is, how do I use the properties of the object in the code for the section that is to display if the object is not null, but not get an error when those properties do not exits in when UPCOMINGEVENTS is null? I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

U might have to use null in stead of !UPCOMINGDATE

```
console.log(!{} === false);   // true
console.log(!{item: "yes"} === false); // true
console.log({item: "yes"} !== null);  // true
console.log({} === null);   // false
```

so it might help using (UPCOMINGDATE !== NULL) then render.

From the dev:
The value null represents the intentional absence of any object value. It is one of JavaScript's primitive values and is treated as falsy for boolean operations.
[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)

short example

```
    import React from 'react'

export default function parent() {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState(null)
React.useEffect(() => {
    getSomeData(id, Callback => {
        // Set the data here
        setEvents(callback)
    })
},[])
    // It will not render the data until its set bc its null
    // You can also map the child 
    return (
        <div>
            {events !== null ? <Child events={events}/> : null}
        </div>
    )
}




export default function Child(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>props.events.title</p>
            <p>props.events.date</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: The UPCOMINGEVENT object has keys: title, date, location, and about. I used those keys later on in the code (ex: <p>{UPCOMINGEVENT.date} | {UPCOMINGEVENT.location}</p>. The issue I am having is when I make the object null, it throws an error saying title, date, location and about are not found. My question is, how do I use the properties of the object in the code for the section that is to display if the object is not null, but not get an error when those properties do not exits in when UPCOMINGEVENTS is null? I hope that makes sense. –

Comment: The way i do it is to load the data in componentDidMount or didmount hook if using function in the parent component if its async fetch use Callback function then set the data to events in the callback. In that parent component render add the conditional with the null operator evaluating the object and if the object isn't null render a child component that you pass the data to . I have done it this way.